# Merging two xml files using xslt after reading a third xml file

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file as below
**propNode.xml**

```
<NODES>
  <NODE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item" TYPE="Item" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item1" TYPE="Item1" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName1" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc1" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item2" TYPE="Item2" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName2" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc2" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
</NODE>
</NODES>
```

I want to read this xml and using it, I need to merge the following two xml files
**source.xml**

```
<NODES>
  <NODE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item" TYPE="Item" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName" VALUE="myNameValue" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc" VALUE="test-myDescValue" />
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId" VALUE="test-myIdValue" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item1" TYPE="Item1" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName1" VALUE="myNameValue1" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc1" VALUE="myDescValue1"/>
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId1" VALUE="myIdValue1" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item2" TYPE="Item2" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName2" VALUE="test-myNameValue2" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc2" VALUE="myDescValue2"/>
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId2" VALUE="test-myIdValue2" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
  </NODE>
</NODES>
```

And **target.xml**

```
<NODES>
  <NODE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item" TYPE="Item" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName" VALUE="myNameValue" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc" VALUE="myDescValue" />
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId" VALUE="myIdValue" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item1" TYPE="Item1" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName1" VALUE="myNameValue1" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc1" VALUE="myDescValue1"/>
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId1" VALUE="myIdValue1" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item2" TYPE="Item2" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName2" VALUE="myNameValue2" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc2" VALUE="myDescValue2"/>
<ATTR_NODE NAME="myId2" VALUE="myIdValue2" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
  </NODE>
</NODES>
```

The condition is reading the propNode.xml, if the value of @NAME matches in the source.xml and target.xml, then the values of @VALUE in the source.xml and target.xml needs to be compared and an output xml should be created as below:

**desiredOutput.xml**

```
<NODES>
  <NODE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item" TYPE="Item" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName" SRCVALUE="myNameValue" TGTVALUE="myNameValue" ISDIFF="false" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc" SRCVALUE="test-myDescValue" TGTVALUE="myDescValue" ISDIFF="true" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item1" TYPE="Item1" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName1" SRCVALUE="myNameValue1" TGTVALUE="myNameValue1" ISDIFF="false" />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc1" SRCVALUE="myDescValue1" TGTVALUE="myDescValue1" ISDIFF="false" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
<NODELINE CLASS="Item2" TYPE="Item2" >
  <ATTR_NODES>
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName2" SRCVALUE="test-myNameValue2" TGTVALUE="myNameValue2" ISDIFF="true" /> />
    <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc2" SRCVALUE="myDescValue2" TGTVALUE="myDescValue2" ISDIFF="false" />
  </ATTR_NODES>
</NODELINE>
  </NODE>
</NODES>
```

The desiredOutput.xml should contain both the values of @VALUE from the source and the target if the value of @NAME selected in the propNode.xml. If the values of @VALUE are different then @ISDIFF should have a value "true" or else "false".

Is this whole operation possible using xslt? Something like generating xsl using the propNode.xml and then applying it on the source.xml and the target.xml to generate the desired output? How would this xsl look like?

Comment: Can you confirm that propnode.xml should also have a `<ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc" />` element in the first `ATTR_NODES`, since this is present in both source, destination as well as desiredOutput?

Comment: @StuartLC yes, sorry my bad. I have edited it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Updated my xslt - must be != of course ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that only the nodes (`ATTR_NODE`) present in `propNode.xml` need to be tested, the following XSLT should do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:my="some.uri" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ATTR_NODE">
        <xsl:variable name="NodeLine" select="../../@CLASS" />
        <xsl:variable name="AttrName" select="@NAME" />
        <xsl:variable name="SrcValue" select="document('source.xml')//NODELINE[@CLASS=$NodeLine]//ATTR_NODE[@NAME=$AttrName]/@VALUE" />
        <xsl:variable name="TgtValue" select="document('target.xml')//NODELINE[@CLASS=$NodeLine]//ATTR_NODE[@NAME=$AttrName]/@VALUE" />
        <xsl:element name="ATTR_NODE">
            <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                <xsl:value-of select="$AttrName"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="SRCVALUE">
                <xsl:value-of select="$SrcValue" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="TGTVALUE">
                <xsl:value-of select="$TgtValue" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ISDIFF">
                <xsl:value-of select="$SrcValue!=$TgtValue" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The identity template is used to traverse and copy `propNode`, with special processing for each `ATTR_NODE` checks `VALUE` in source and target, and then evaluated for equality. I've assumed that `NODE_LINE/@CLASS` is sufficient to establish the identity of the `NODE_LINE` - if it isn't, then you'll need to add additional checking e.g. `@TYPE` as well.

The xslt is run against `propnode.xml`, and `source.xml` and `target.xml` must be present in the same folder.

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NODES>
    <NODE>
        <NODELINE CLASS="Item" TYPE="Item">
            <ATTR_NODES>
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName" SRCVALUE="myNameValue" TGTVALUE="myNameValue" ISDIFF="false" />
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc" SRCVALUE="test-myDescValue" TGTVALUE="myDescValue" ISDIFF="true" />"
            </ATTR_NODES>
        </NODELINE>
        <NODELINE CLASS="Item1" TYPE="Item1">
            <ATTR_NODES>
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName1" SRCVALUE="myNameValue1" TGTVALUE="myNameValue1" ISDIFF="false" />
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc1" SRCVALUE="myDescValue1" TGTVALUE="myDescValue1" ISDIFF="false" />
            </ATTR_NODES>
        </NODELINE>
        <NODELINE CLASS="Item2" TYPE="Item2">
            <ATTR_NODES>
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myName2" SRCVALUE="test-myNameValue2" TGTVALUE="myNameValue2" ISDIFF="true" />
                <ATTR_NODE NAME="myDesc2" SRCVALUE="myDescValue2" TGTVALUE="myDescValue2" ISDIFF="false" />
            </ATTR_NODES>
        </NODELINE>
    </NODE>
</NODES>
```